# SDL_Surface refuse to blit

Tags: c++, blit, sdl-2

I'm trying to make a very little and simple snippet with SDL. This one works like a charm :

```
SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDLTest", 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_SWSURFACE);
screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
SDL_Color color={0,0,0};
TTF_GlyphMetrics(font, ch, &minx, &maxx, &miny, &maxy, NULL);
SDL_Surface * car =TTF_RenderGlyph_Blended(font,ch,color);
SDL_Rect textRect = {offsetX, offsetY, 0, 0};
if(SDL_BlitSurface( car, NULL, glyph, &screen ))
qDebug() << SDL_GetError();
```

and this one doesn't work at all :

```
SDL_Surface * glyph = NULL;
SDL_Surface * car = TTF_RenderGlyph_Blended(font,ch,color);
qDebug() << TTF_GetError();
SDL_Rect textRect = {0, 0, car->w, car->h};
if(SDL_BlitSurface( car, NULL, glyph, &textRect ))
qDebug() << SDL_GetError();
```

`TTF_GetError()` return nothing so I assume `TTF_RenderGlyph_Blended` works well and `SDL_GetError()` send me this :

> > SDL_UpperBlit: passed a NULL surface

::::::::::::::::: EDIT ::::::::::::::::::

Ok, I've fix the NULL problem, but the blit is not good yet:

```
ch = 66;
SDL_Surface * glyph = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font, "Z", color);
SDL_UnlockSurface(glyph);
SDL_Surface * car = TTF_RenderGlyph_Blended(font,ch,color);
SDL_Rect textRect = {0, 0, car->w, car->h};
qDebug() << SDL_BlitSurface(car, NULL, glyph, &textRect);
qDebug() << SDL_BlitSurface(glyph, NULL, screen, &textRect);
```

Should display `B` but go `Z` instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [MahamGM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520499/mahangm) said, there was a format issue which is solved now :

```
Uint32 rmask, gmask, bmask, amask;
rmask = 0x000000ff;
gmask = 0x0000ff00;
bmask = 0x00ff0000;
amask = 0xff000000;


ch = 65;
SDL_Surface * glyph = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,screen->w,screen->h,32,rmask,gmask,bmask,amask);
SDL_Surface * car = TTF_RenderGlyph_Blended(font,ch,color);

SDL_Rect glyphRect = {0, 0, 100, 100};
SDL_Rect carRect = {100, 0, 300, 300};

PHDEBUG << SDL_BlitSurface(car, NULL, glyph, &glyphRect);
PHDEBUG << SDL_BlitSurface(glyph, NULL, screen, &glyphRect);
```

Answer (score 3):

[SDL_BlitSurface](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitSurface) requires source surface (your **car** variable) and destination surface (your **glyph** variable). Your first snippet doesn't show how and where is **glyph** created, but your second snippet explicitly sets **glyph** to **NULL**.

You should assign created surface to **glyph** before using it in SDL_BlitSurface function.

Edit:
For rendering glyphs on surface, first create new surface, fill it with background color, and then blit glyph on it. You can use rectangle to define blit position if you want:

```
SDL_Surface * glyph = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 100, 100, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SDL_FillRect(glyph, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(glyph->format, 255, 255, 255);

ch = 66;
SDL_Surface * car = TTF_RenderGlyph_Blended(font, ch, color);

qDebug() << SDL_BlitSurface(car, NULL, glyph, NULL);
qDebug() << SDL_BlitSurface(glyph, NULL, screen, NULL);
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what are you trying to accomplish, but you can try this code instead:
`ch = 66;
SDL_Surface * car = TTF_RenderGlyph_Blended(font,ch,color);
SDL_Surface * glyph = SDL_ConvertSurface(car, car->format, car->flags);
SDL_Rect textRect = {0, 0, car->w, car->h};
qDebug() << SDL_BlitSurface(glyph, NULL, screen, &textRect);`

Comment: I want to create a home-made glyph (like this one : http://fc04.deviantart.net/images/i/2003/7/5/2/Times_New_dirty_Roman.jpg) from a given font. I start with one char to test the routine. Even if your snippet work I'm not sure it can handle this.

Comment: So, basically, you want to blit several glyphs onto one big surface?

Answer (score 1):

Manual says you shouldn't call for locked surfaces when using `SDL_BlitSurface()`. Try to `SDL_UnlockSurface()` before call `SDL_BlitSurface()` for your surfaces. And for more information check what is the returned value of `SDL_BlitSurface()`. Before that you have to check for source surface to see whether it's filled or not, and try to use `SDL_FillRect()` on destination surface before blitting and see what happens.

Although, check for correct surface format:

http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitSurface#Remarks

Comment: Well, the only possibility left is to check your `textRect`. Try pass `NULL` since you're not doing anything different than setting on zero coordinates.

Comment: Have you tried to drawing images instead of texts? If this is not working well it means the problem is hid in other places.

Comment: Well `glyph` blit on the `screen` surface and an SDL_Image blit correctly too. I just can't blit `car` on `glyph`

Comment: SDL's wiki page says that surfaces with different blendings and colorkeys are blitted upon their formats. http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitSurface#Remarks check for formats part. Maybe there is a blending problem with your surfaces.

Comment: You're half right, it works a bit with Solid instead of Blended... But steel unusable

Comment: I haven't worked with SDL2 yet, but my guess is, `TTF_RenderGlyph_Blended()` is generating a different surface format than what you think.

Comment: Yep. Well played. I'm gonna check this